# Add client certificate and SSL to python app calling Elasticsearch

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, ssl-certificate, elasticsearch-2.0

So I have an Elasticsearch cluster that I have been accessing from .Net web services via a ACL protected http endpoint.  I have spun up a new reverse proxy that uses SSL and requires a client certificate to forward the request on to the (now protected) Elasticsearch cluster.

I have this all working fine in .Net, but I have one service that I inherited that running Python.  I have not worked with Python much, and am struggling to figure out how to implement this.

I am using ES 2.3.2 and Python 3.2.

For .Net, I have the certificate installed on the hosting machine where the code pulls it directly from the store.  I have used OpenSSL and exported this into a .pem (as well as .crt and .key as well).  The problems I am encountering are A) how to get the transport to be https instead of http, and B) how to include my cert.  I first tried:

```
client = Elasticsearch(hosts=[self.host], timeout=80, use_ssl=True, verify_certs=True, client_cert=cert_file_path, client_key=key_file_path)
```

This does not seem to work.  So I figured I needed to build up my own connection/transport, so I tried this:

```
    connection = Urllib3HttpConnection(host=self.host['host'], port=self.host['port'], use_ssl=True,ca_certs=cert_file_path, client_cert=cert_file_path, client_key=key_file_path, verify_certs=True )
    transport = Transport(hosts=[self.host], connection_class=connection)
    client = Elasticsearch(hosts=[self.host], timeout=80, use_ssl=True, verify_certs=True, Transport=transport, client_cert=cert_file_path, client_key=key_file_path)
```

I need to manually in the debugger change the scheme to 'https', but when I run now, I get:

```
TypeError("'Urllib3HttpConnection' object is not callable",)
```

In .Net what I am doing is overriding the HttpConnection in the ConnectionSetings for the ElasticClient.  In it, I override CreateHttpWebRequest and add my certificate to the the outbound request:

```
// add the cert to the collection

webRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(this.clientCertificate);
```

It seems this should be a common thing to do, but I can't figure it out (though that could be due to my lack of python experience).

Any help out there?

Thanks!
~john

**UPDATE**

So here is the definition of my host:

```
{"use_ssl": True, "host": "[my server].cloudapp.net", "port": "443", "scheme": "https", "transport_schema": "https"}
```

From the [documentation](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.0/api.html):

```
kwargs – any additional arguments will be passed on to the Transport class and, subsequently, to the Connection instances.
```

I would assume that the scheme and/or transport_schema would be forwarded on through.

I create the client as:

```
client = Elasticsearch(hosts=[self.host], timeout=80, use_ssl=True, scheme="https", verify_certs=True, client_cert=cert_file_path, client_key=key_file_path)
```

When I create the client, I get:

```
ERROR  Exception encountered.  Detailed info: ImproperlyConfigured('Scheme specified in connection (https) is not the same as the connection class (Urllib3HttpConnection) specifies (http).',)
```

This is happening in transport.py in _create_connection():

```
        if 'scheme' in host and host['scheme'] != self.connection_class.transport_schema:

            raise ImproperlyConfigured(

                'Scheme specified in connection (%s) is not the same as the connection class (%s) specifies (%s).' % (

                    host['scheme'], self.connection_class.__name__, self.connection_class.transport_schema

            ))
```

When I break here, I can see that:

self.kwargs['transport_schema'] = 'https'

but:

self.connection_class.transport_schema = 'http'

I would have thought that the kwarg would have been forwarded on to the connection_class.  I manually set the transport_schema to 'https' and this allows me to get past this error.

So that is the first part.  After doing this, I get a certificate validation error.  This is probably resolveable, I just haven't been through to this part yet.  The problems here are:

A) I am prompted for a pass phrase.  How can I supply this?  This is a service that will be running unattended.

B) Anyway, when I supply it, I get:

GET https://[my server].cloudapp.net:443/ocv_int/_search?request_cache=true [status:N/A request:6.085s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Source\Repos\OfficeCustomerVoice\UserExperience\OCVClusteringWebAPI\env3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 578, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "E:\Source\Repos\OfficeCustomerVoice\UserExperience\OCVClusteringWebAPI\env3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 351, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "E:\Source\Repos\OfficeCustomerVoice\UserExperience\OCVClusteringWebAPI\env3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 814, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "E:\Source\Repos\OfficeCustomerVoice\UserExperience\OCVClusteringWebAPI\env3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 289, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "E:\Source\Repos\OfficeCustomerVoice\UserExperience\OCVClusteringWebAPI\env3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 308, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\jthoni\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3-2-3\lib\ssl.py", line 365, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "C:\Users\jthoni\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3-2-3\lib\ssl.py", line 583, in **init**
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\jthoni\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3-2-3\lib\ssl.py", line 810, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Source\Repos\OfficeCustomerVoice\UserExperience\OCVClusteringWebAPI\env3\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 94, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=self.headers, **kw)
  File "E:\Source\Repos\OfficeCustomerVoice\UserExperience\OCVClusteringWebAPI\env3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 604, in urlopen
    raise SSLError(e)
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)

P.S. to get my cert files I did the following with my pfx file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in E:\[myCert].pfx -out E:\[myCert].pem -nodes
openssl pkcs12 -in E:\[myCert].pfx -nocerts -out E:\[myCert].key
openssl pkcs12 -in E:\[myCert].pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out E:\[myCert].crt
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback.

Comment: Added info as edit.

Comment: I changed:

 verify_certs=False

And now I get:
 b9284864-dbbb-458b-92ba-0e69450c6c6e ERROR  Exception encountered.  Detailed info: AuthorizationException(403, '', None)

This tells me that I don't have my cert configured correctly, but not sure how to resolve.